# Nao retorna todos os resultados do xml

Tags: php, xml

estou com um prolema nesse leitor de xml, ele so faz a leitura do primeiro item do xml, alguem pode me ajudar? Obrigado

```
<?php
$link = "http://war.deathface.com.br/wo/api_getserverinfo.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($link); 

foreach($xml -> news as $dados){ 
    echo "<strong>Título:</strong> ".utf8_decode($dados -> news['name'])."<br />";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente outro loop

```
foreach($xml->news as $v) { 
    foreach($v as $vv){
    echo "<pre>";
        print_r($vv['name']);
    echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: vlw, deu certo..

Comment: talvez tenha outra maneira pela propria lib da funcao xml_read_file().